# Bayesian network and fuzzy logic

Tags: matlab, neural-network, bayesian, bayesian-networks, fuzzy-logic

Can anyone give me an example of a Bayesian network and fuzzy logic being used in intrusion detection?

I'm struggling to figure out how it can be used. And any code on it?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact details will depend upon whether you're talking about a burglar alarm type situation (sensor readings) or something fancier involving security guards and sharks with lasers.  Either way, the principle is the same.

You start with root nodes describing the basic things that affect intrusion, e.g.,

```
Sensor detected motion (true/false)  
Shark smelt blood (true/false)
Temperature (too low/just right/too high)
Security guard is asleep
...  
any other things you can think of.
```

You assign a probability to each state of each root node.

```
P(Security guard is asleep) = 0.25
```

Then you define child nodes that depend upon those root nodes, e.g., `Security guard heard noise` would depend upon `Security guard is asleep`.

You assign conditional probabilities for each state of the child nodes, given each state of its parents.

```
P(Security guard heard noise|Security guard is asleep) = 0.05
P(Security guard heard noise|Security guard is not asleep) = 0.5
```

Eventually, you'll want to get to an outcome like `Burglary has been foiled`.

Once you have your network node set up, you can evaluate it, and calculate the probability of different outcomes happening.

Next you add evidence.  So if you know your shark smelt blood, that node gets set to a particular value and you can reevaluate the network to see how probabilities have changed.

In terms of software, the [Bayes Net](https://code.google.com/p/bnt/) toolbox is well regarded.

Comment: already have matlab cant find bayes net toolbox tho and looking at the comments on install for that one you linked looks abit :S. That was a great help tho im glad someone can use great analogies for the laymen :D very well put. What about fuzy logic? How can we have a "degree" of false/true positive?

Comment: All the Fuzzy-logic examples I've seen can be mapped easily to Bayes-nets. 

Bayes nets solve these problems rigorously. As far as I can tell Fuzzy logic just does things that sound reasonable.

A degree of true/false is very natural in Bayes-nets because the network doesn't track what did happen, it tracks what your degree of belief should be given the network, and the evidence you've supplied.